# Using Rscript in Linux server

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, r

I have an R file `test.R` that I want to run on my account on a school linux server using the command:

```
Rscript test.R
```

I copied R 3.1.2 into my directory on the server, which I'll call  "home/mydirectory" for simpilicity.

[image]

When I run Rscript test.R I get this error:

> `-bash: Rscript: command not found`

I tried setting the Rscript path in nano ~/.bashrc, but I don't seem to have the syntax correct.

Try 1:

```
export Rscript = "/home/mydirectory/R-3.1.2/bin/Rscript.exe":$Rscript
```

Try 2:

```
export Rscript = "/home/mydirectory/R-3.1.2/bin/Rscript":$Rscript
```

I also tried this command to run it directly without success.

```
shell_exec("/home/mydirectory/R-3.1.2/bin/Rscript") test.R
```

Any suggestions to correctly set the path/environmental variables so that this works? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
export PATH="$PATH:/home/mydirectory/R-3.1.2/bin/"
```

Some further explanation:

Your path variable points to directories that the shell should search for commands, not directly to the path of each command. Just adding R's `bin` directory to `$PATH` is all the shell needs in order to find the Rscript program.